# Erase/delete parts of a GraphicsPath?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, paint, gdi+

How would I approach making an eraser for a Paint-type application, when my free drawing is done with lines stored in a `GraphicsPath`?

I've tried the following, but it looks like the `Points` `IEnumerable` is read-only. The tricky part is that I have to keep a thin border around the painted strokes so the eraser would have to maintain the border around the remaining `GraphicsPath`.

Here's what I tried to remove part of the `GraphicsPath`:

```
    private void Testform_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            List <PointF> list = _drawingPath.PathData.Points.ToList<PointF>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                list.RemoveAt(i);
            }

            Invalidate();
        }        
    }
```

That bit is just for testing hence no exception handling and the arbitrary use of 50. If you scribble a bit on the form you'll end up with more than 50 points to test.

And here is my complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Cartographer
{
    public partial class testform : Form
    {

        private GraphicsPath _drawingPath = new GraphicsPath();
        private Point lastMouseLocation;
        private bool drawing = false;

        public testform()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void testform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Paint += Testform_Paint;
            this.MouseMove += Testform_MouseMove;
            this.MouseDown += Testform_MouseDown;

            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        }

        private void Testform_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                List <PointF> list = _drawingPath.PathData.Points.ToList<PointF>();

                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                {
                    list.RemoveAt(i);
                }

                Invalidate();
            }        
        }

        private void Testform_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                drawing = true;
                _drawingPath.AddLine(lastMouseLocation, e.Location);
                Invalidate();
            }

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.None && drawing)
            {
                drawing = false;
                _drawingPath.StartFigure();

            }
            lastMouseLocation = e.Location;


        }

        private void Testform_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
            e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue))
            using (Pen p = new Pen(b, 51))
            {
                p.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
                p.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
                p.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset;

                e.Graphics.DrawPath(p, _drawingPath);

            }

            using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.LightGreen))
            using (Pen p = new Pen(b, 50))
            {
                p.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
                p.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
                p.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset;



                e.Graphics.DrawPath(p, _drawingPath);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

If you try it for yourself you'll notice the border I need to maintain. All I need to figure out is how to erase parts of the drawing while maintaining the border.

Thank you!

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)`  Where's the 50 coming from?  If you only draw a little, you will throw an index out of range exception.

Comment: @LarsTech just arbitrary, for testing. It's easy to draw more than 50 points, just scribble a bit and no exception. I'll clarify in my post. Any ideas for a solution to the erasing, though?

Comment: You only want to delete the inside color, not the outside border?

Comment: @LarsTech I need to preserve the border, as in if a point is removed from the main `GraphicsPath`, the border should draw around the edit. It should adapt to any deletion. If I can figure out a way to simply delete points from the `GraphicsPath`, my current method of drawing the border should adapt automatically. Do you know a way to edit points in an existing `GraphicsPath`?

Comment: Probably easier to delete the line entirely then recreate by omitting the points that were "erased".

Comment: @LarsTech I see. That's not computationally ideal, but I suppose I'll have to give it a shot.